# How to run function in python on background and still continue the main flow?

Tags: python

I currently create website with Flask. After user sign up, i want to send mail & execute insert into sql, but it run slow, so i want to execute it on background and still continue the main flow and return the html without stuck on loading page.

```
def send_email_and_insert():
    # some smtplib code here
    # and some insert into sql too
    # this  function make the web stuck loading 5-10 second


@app.route('/sign_up/')
def sign_up():
    # some code here
    send_email_and_insert()
    return render_template('thanks_for_sign_up.html')
```

I think it can be done with multiprocessing or threading, but i cant get it right. or maybe there is another solution?

Comment: Show what attempts you've made to use threading, and narrow this question down to something specific regarding your attempt

Comment: 'from multiprocessing import Process


#and on sign_up()
p = Process(target=send_email_and_insert)
p.start()
p.join()`

Comment: That's not really an attempt. Have you read any tutorials? This question is far too broad right now.

Comment: When using a web framework like Flask, an asynchronous queue like Celery is way more popular than threading.